# jQuery click on a dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I created a HTML table using jQuery and I'd like to perform a click on the first link inside the 2nd row.
The generated HTML looks like this

```
<tr><td>4</td><td>text</td></tr>
<tr id="xrow22" class="xrow"><td colspan="2"><a>0</a><a>1</a></td></tr>
```

The function handling clicks works well when I click the row using my mouse

```
$('table').on('click', '[id^=xrow] a', function(){ ...
```

When I try to call this function from another one, it doesn't work. I used alert to see some values and surprisingly the below code alerts (2nd value should be 0)

```
<a>0</a><a>1</a>,,[object Object]
```

Code:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr:not(.xrow)', function(e){
  $(this).next().children('td:first-child a:first-child').click();
  alert($(this).next().children('td:first-child').html() +','+ $(this).next().children('td:first-child a:first-child').text() +','+ $(this).next().children('td:first-child a:first-child'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use `$(this).next().children('td:first-child').children('a:first-child').text();` I get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the $().on() function you can use the $().live() function. Basically when you create a new element, jquery doesn't rerun and attach the click even to it.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: When I change it in one of or both places, the code stops working completely